# jQuery css to change element background but not element:hover background

Tags: jquery, css

basically I am using jquery cycle, and it has a wrapper for the numerical navigation to navigate the slideshows.

```
<div id="slide_nav">
<a href="#">1</a>
<a href="#">2</a>
<a href="#">3</a>
</div>
```

the css is :

```
#slide_nav a { 
  background: #d5d5d5; 
}

#slide_nav a.activeSlide,#slide_nav a:hover { 
  background: #272727; 
}
```

then i want to use jquery to change the background of the second and third navigation, since I'm aware that CSS nth selector will not work at all browsers (is it true? kinda forgot). so here's my jquery:

```
$('#slide_nav a:nth-child(2)').css({"background-color" : "green","color" : "#fff"});
$('#slide_nav a:nth-child(3)').css({"background-color" : "blue","color" : "#fff"});
```

so it's a success, my 2nd n 3rd navigation change colors. However the problem is, the css a:hover rule doesn't work, meaning if i hover the 2nd and 3rd navigation, it doesn't change bg color to #272727 anymore, it stays on green and blue for 2nd and 3rd navigation, but it works for the first navigation which I left out of the jquery rule.

is there a way to use jquery to change the background of the a but leave the a:hover rule to css external stylesheet?

EDIT : I'm using Firefox 3.5

Comment: please clarfiy, you're using a css rule for a:hover which changes the background? What's wrong with it?

Comment: yeah, my inital bg color for the #slidenav is #d5d5d5, then on hover, it is #272727. I can do that using CSS a:hover just fine.

then suddenly, things change, They want the 2nd and 3rd nav (number 2 and 3) become green and blue. Since CSS3 selector isn't widely supported, i choose to use jquery selector.

it worked, but i don't know why, the a:hover rule doesn't work anymore, meaning if i hover the 2nd and 3rd navigation, it doesn't change bg color to #272727, it stays greeen for 2nd and blue for 3rd navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a class instead of your jquery css. And changes in your style block will be like this:

```
#slide_nav a { 
  background: #d5d5d5; 
}

#slide_nav a.activeSlide,#slide_nav a:hover { 
  background: #272727 !important; 
}

a.child1{
 color: #fff
 background-color: green;
}

a.child2{
 color: #fff
 background-color: green;
}
```

And use this jquery:

```
$('#slide_nav a:nth-child(2)').addClass(child1);
$('#slide_nav a:nth-child(3)').addClass(child2);
```

PS the solutions wasn't tested but it should work (may require some adjustments). The idea was to avoid jquery styling and replace it with classes.

Comment: thanks so much! i forgot about the !important syntax!

apparently, i only need to add !important to the background on hover. 

problem solved.